# How to access the Guice injector throughout application

Tags: java, guice, thrift

I've just started using Guice and after reading the docs, skimming through a few books and watching the 2009 Google I/O talk I'm trying to convert a thrift project that relies on a few global data structures. At the moment they're created when the thrift server starts and passed to the handler on each request. They're also used in every part of the code! Essentially singletons.

As I understand it's best practice to create the injector in your main method and load all you're modules once.

I'm not sure how I'm meant to use this injector somewhere else in my code. Should I wrap it in a singleton class and litter my code with

```
Injector injector = InjectorInstance.get();
ClassA obj = injector.getInstance(ClassA.class);
```

Or is there a method I don't know about

```
ClassA obj = Guice.getLastInjector().getInstance(ClassA.class);
```

I've also found a recommendation to pass around Providers but I'm not sure how that's any better than passing the actual data structures down the call stack.

If someone could explain the recommended pattern, or even better send me in the direction of a good open source project that uses guice I would be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Guice, the idea is that you have an entire graph of dependencies, each of which keeps a reference to the things it needs across its lifetime:

```
class EntryPoint {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    YourApp yourApp = Guice.createInjector(yourListOfModules())
        .getInstance(YourApp.class);
    yourApp.run();
  }
}

class YourApp {
  @Inject DependencyA dependencyA;
}

class DependencyA {
  @Inject DependencyB dependencyB;
}

class DependencyB {
  /** This is injected once, so you'll always only get the same instance. */
  @Inject DependencyC dependencyC;
  /** By injecting the provider, you can get multiple instances. */
  @Inject Provider<DependencyD> dependencyD;
}
```

Guice takes care of the plumbing, so YourApp and DependencyA don't need to worry about whether DependencyB needs DependencyC or DependencyD. In this sense, you never call `new`: Guice takes care of creating every `@Inject`ed dependency for you, and then supplying its dependencies.

If you haven't plumbed through your dependencies (i.e. you still call `new` in your code), you'll no longer have access to the Injector from the manually-constructed class. In that case you may want to use `getInstance` or `getProvider` and stash it away in a static field. Guice will also help you do this with [requestStaticInjection](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestStaticInjection%28java.lang.Class%3c?%3e...%29), which is not great for long-term Guice design but may help you work with legacy code or transitioning into Guice.

Comment: I think I get it now I'll have to try this, thank you for the great explanation!